# do we have any updated guide to integrate the frontier to the substrate solo-chain?

Tags: frontier, solo-chain

I want to integrate the frontier with my existing substrate solo-chain. do we have any guide/resource to help in that?

substrate version i am using polkadot-v1.0.0

Comment: Can you please improve your question by specifying if its a solochain or a parachain?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into this repository: [Frontier Parachain Template](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier-parachain-template) is a ready-to-use EVM-based parachain.

You can use specifically [this commit](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier-parachain-template/commit/60142f5b95139b00400e47d4a414c87405be9a5f) to see the changes needed to add the Frontier integration.